# What do I do if a university does not inform me of my masters application status?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I have applied to a Canadian university to study a Masters degree starting Fall 2013, and they didn't accept or reject me, the online application clearly states that I will get notified by an email of their decision and I am pretty sure I didn't receive any emails from them (yes, I check my spam folder everyday).

Do I have any recourse for recouping my application fee? Whom do I contact for this information?

Comment: you can start by trying to contact them and ask what happened with your application, and why they haven't contacted you despite the application states otherwise.

Comment: The application states is still "UNDER REVIEW IN DEPARTMENT" I will try to contact them, but the idea is that they did not fulfill their part of the deal (That is replying to me by an email) so I want to know if anyone faced such a situation and did he/she take any measures to get refunds and what happened?!

Comment: You probably can take them to small claims court and sue for your application fee to be returned. You might even "win" and get the $100 or so back. I doubt they have caused any damages to you.

Comment: @ Daniel E. Shub well other than sever headaches caused by application filling and recommendation letters acquisition and postal services to send them my transcripts, TOEFL and GRE report cards, no they didn't cause much damage.

Comment: Surely this could have been cleared up if you had sent them an email months ago and politely asked about your status.  A court might say that's what you should have done, it's called mitigating damages.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't start by threatening them with a lawsuit.  You could try asking for a refund of the application fee, and maybe they'll give it to you.  However, you'll probably have to explain why you didn't ask them about it while there was still time to fix the problem.

Comment: One possibility is that they have the wrong e-mail address on record.

Comment: @Joel Reyes Noche I have received emails from them confirming recipient of application fees and for starting the online application.

Comment: Do you live in Canada? If so, how close to that university?

Comment: Also, did you actually remind them - by phone and/or in writing - about your application? Maybe "the dog ate the letter" which they were about to send you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple questions that remain unanswered here:

- Did you meet all of the deadlines for the admissions process?
- Did the people who wrote your letters of recommendation send in their references on time?
- Did the school promise you a reply-by date?
- If so, why did you not contact them at that time?
- Did you get an email confirming that the application was complete?

If any of those were missing, then it's entirely possible that you didn't have a complete application—in which case, the school is not necessarily required to do anything, because they don't have a complete record to consider.

Moreover, a lawsuit is a horrifically bad idea under the circumstances—it's far more time-consuming and expensive than anything you're going to get back from the school. It's a waste of your time and money (unless they rather unlikely made written promises of admission, in which case they may be in bigger legal troubles than just having to return an admission fee).

Comment: I will answer your questions one by one (1)Yes I meet all their deadlines (2) Yes the reference letters reached the university on time (3) No they didn't give me an exact date, they said that they will inform me with the decision they make by email (logically before the semester starts) (4) I was patiently waiting for their email (5) I got an email that confirms my application fees payment and the online application status tracker says that my application is complete, and currently being reviewed by the department.